# How to trigger mat chip error validation?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm doing a error validation for a field with mat-chip, I'm able to pop up the error validation message only after user add a single mat-chip value, then remove the value. I want to make it where when user click on the field then go to a next field of the form without adding any value, it'll already trigger the error message. Below is my code snippet

HTML :

```
<form [formGroup]="positionForm">
  <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="space-between stretch">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Title</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName="title" type="text" placeholder="Title" required>
      <mat-error *ngIf="positionForm.controls.title.invalid">This field is required.</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field class="chip-list" appearance="outline" (click)="formValue()">
    <mat-label>Skills *</mat-label>
    <mat-chip-list #chipSkills>
      <mat-chip *ngFor="let skill of positionForm.get('skills').controls; let i = index" [selectable]="selectable"
                [removable]="removable" (removed)="removeSkills(i)" (click)="formValue()">
        {{skill.value}}
        <mat-icon class="remove-chip" matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
      </mat-chip>
      <input placeholder="Enter Skills..."
             [matChipInputFor]="chipSkills"
             [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
             [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
             (matChipInputTokenEnd)="addEditSkill($event)" required>
    </mat-chip-list>
    <mat-error  *ngIf="positionForm.controls.skills.errors">Atleast 1 skill need to be added </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

TS :

```
title = new FormControl('', [Validators.required,this.customValidator.NoWhiteSpaceValidator]);
skills = new FormArray([], [Validators.required, this.validateArrayNotEmpty] );


validateArrayNotEmpty(chip: FormControl) {
  if (chip.value && chip.value.length === 0) {
    return {
      validateArrayNotEmpty: { valid: false }
    };
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Try you add this code
`@ViewChild('chipList') chipList: MatChipList;

ngOnInit() {
  this.myForm.get('names').statusChanges.subscribe(
    status => this.chipList.errorState = status === 'INVALID'
  );
}`

Comment: [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4d5vfj-gywxjz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4d5vfj-gywxjz)

Comment: Hi @er-sho thank you for your assist but when I set you array to empty at beginning you also have the same issue as I do, the error wouldnt come out if its empty at the beginning and I click on it and click out, it doesnt trigger